# iOS application that allows search in Word documents?

Tags: text-editor, search, text

I have a huge .doc (Microsoft Word) file (several megabytes) and I need to search it on my iPhone. I have tried like 5 different editors and readers to no avail.

Is there any application that allows searching in .doc files?

Comment: Which specific apps have you tried already? And by doc you mean Microsoft Word I assume?

Comment: Yes, microsoft word. I have tried Files, and couple other editors I don't remember as I deleted them.

Comment: Do you just need to search/lookup or also to edit the files?

Comment: @patrix only search and go to the page with found phrase

Comment: You have an historic of purchased applications in the App Store: Updates > Purchase. A list of the things you tried will save us time to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an app for that. It is called QuickOffice, it costs 14.99$ and I had to break file into three to make it work. But the search is there and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The app "[Documents](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/documents-by-readdle/id364901807?mt=8)" referred to above is a good option. It searches inside the documents whether the files are PDF, docx, etc… It sports a clean interface and plenty of remote connection options. And not to mention, it's free with no ads!

Give it a go and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

there's a program called "documents" in app store (its free) that lets you search for the word you want =]

Comment: There are several apps matching "Documents" in the App Store. Can you provide some more details (including a link) and also describe how this apps can be used to search through Word documents?

Answer (score 0):

Documents by Readdle is the app and it is very simple to use

Comment: can you provide a link?

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/documents-by-readdle/id364901807?mt=8